# How to add numbered suffixes in MS Word doc?

Tags: microsoft-word-2016, documents, numbering

I have a few headings spread through out an MS Word document. I would like these headings numbered so that if I remove one, add a new one etc the rest adjust accordingly just like a numbered list. The tricky part is that I would like the number as a suffix at the end of the heading eg. Heading 1, Heading 2 etc.

Is there a way to do this or will I just need to do this manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to insert the Field code:

- Go to *Insert>Quick Parts>Field...>select AutoNum>select 1,2,3,...>enter a space in the **Separator character** box>click OK*.
- Then press `Alt` + `F9` to display the complete field code. And copy and paste the code behind the other headings.
- Press `Alt` + `F9` again to display the numbers.

Code:  `{AUTONUM \* Arabic \s " "}`
If you want to add the above code manually, please note that the "**{}**" symbol must be added by `Ctrl` + `F9`.

[image]